# Best way to calculate local density of states of tight binding model

Tags: condensed-matter, density-of-states, tight-binding

I am currently trying to analyze a system using a tight binding model. I have a quite complicated unit cell with more than nearest neighbor hopping, that is repeating in one dimension. I have a matrix $V$ that describes the hopping of electrons within the unit cells and a matrix $T$ that describes the hopping between unit cells. I am interested in the bulk properties of this system, and have been able to get the band structure by considering an infinite array of unit cells, and then Fourier transforming and diagonalising the resulting matrix numerically. I am now trying to calculate the density of states of this system, what would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Do you know the degeneracy of the energy levels?

Comment: Yes, the bands are non-degenerate, except that they some times cross each other.